# Notation in a paper on quantum mechanics and gravitation (2)

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am currently reading the paper "Gravitation and quantum mechanics for macroscopic objects" by F. Karolyhazy (1966).

The author defines formally rigorous equations in order to describe the decay of the pure state $\Phi(\vec x_i)$ at $t=0$ into a mixture of states $\Phi_1(\vec x_i), \Phi_2(\vec x_i)$ with their corresponding probabilities. He then defines a quantity $$\omega_{\chi} = average over \beta |(\Psi_\beta(\vec x_i, t), \chi(\vec x_i))|^2$$ where $\chi(\vec x_i)$ is an arbitrary, normalized function. He also defines a set $(P_k; \Phi_k(\vec x_i)$) by making $$\omega_{\chi} = P_1 |(\Phi_1, \chi)|^2 + P_2 |(\Phi_2, \chi)|^2 +...$$ for every $\chi$. And then he maximizes average over $\beta \sum_k|(\Phi_{k\beta}, \Phi_k)|^2$, in which 
$$\Phi_{k\beta}(\vec x_i) = \exp[-(i/\hbar)\int_0^t H_\beta dt] \exp[(i/\hbar)\int_0^tHdt]\phi_k(\vec x_i)$$ where

$$H_{\beta} = \sum_i - \frac{\hbar}{2m_i} \Delta_i + \sum_{i} \gamma(\vec x_i, t) m_i c^2+\sum_{ik} V_{ik}$$
and $$H= \sum_i - \frac{\hbar}{2m_i} \Delta_i + \sum_{ik} V_{ik}$$ I could not understand the point of $\omega_\chi$ or even $\chi$ for that matter. Also, I suspect the Hamiltonians are incorrect. What is the point of the various terms and the complicated Hamiltonians?

---

Note: I can attach pictures of the paper here if needed.

Comment: What's $\beta$, especially: What is its range, given that it is averaged over?

Comment: It is a parameter. That's all it is haha. And no range specified. He uses it as the index for the set of matter free manifolds.